# Is assigning an inverse-Wishart distribution to a diagonal matrix problematic?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, wishart-distribution

I'm reading the paper [Bayesian Vector Autoregressions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5413/14d103bad39828e493154829a5ef093a78e3.pdf) by Thomas Wozniak. He considers the model
$$y_t = \mu + A_1 y_{t-1} + \cdots A_k y_{t-k} + u_t$$ where each $y_i$ is a $N$-vector, each $A_j$ is a $N\times N$ matrix and $u_t \sim N(0, \Sigma)$

He assigns the prior for $\Sigma$ to be inverse Wishart. I think that
the errors are independent, which would mean that $\Sigma$ is diagonal. If this is the case, then $N^2 - N$ of the entries are zero (i.e. non-random). If this is not the case, I am working with a similar model where the covariance matrix is diagonal. In either case, I am led me to the following question:

> Is it okay to assign the inverse Wishart distribution to diagonal matrix?

Comment: What makes you think that the error covariance matrix is diagonal? I have never seen that assumed in the context of VARs.

Comment: I believe the errors are independent.

Comment: Over time yes, but literally no one assumes that $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Maybe you are conflicting two different notions of independence. You typically assume time independence ($u_t$ and $u_s$ are independent for $t\neq s$), but that is different from cross-sectional independence which you do *not* assume. The latter would entail assuming that $u_{i,t}$ and $u_{j,t}$ are independent for $i\neq j$ and would yield a diagonal $\Sigma$. But no one makes that assumption, so $\Sigma$ is never diagonal in this context.

Comment: That makes sense. I've never heard the term cross-sectional independence before.

Comment: Time independence: $\text{Cov}(u_t, u_s) = 0$ if $t \neq s$. Cross-sectional independence: $\text{Var}(u_t)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, under normality of the error term

Comment: On page 27 of the working paper Dynamic hierarchical factor models (https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/60828/1/622842811.pdf) the assume the covariance matrix is diagonal.

Comment: But a key difference I see is that in the working paper they are assuming the errors are autoregressive, instead of the response variable.

Comment: I realize that the comments are now a bit lengthy. You don't have to continue responding. Your input has been very helpful.

Comment: The paper you link to deals with a dynamic factor model. That is not a VAR model (although you may encounter VAR structures elsewhere, I was under the impression you were talking about VAR models as discussed in the paper linked to in the original post).